# Rake db:Migrate with Nginx Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

I'm running a server with Nginx, Capistrano, Rails

I made some db:migrations on my local machine and then want to push them to these changes to my server. However I can't figure out how to migrate my database on the server. How do I do this?

**I've Tried**

1)

```
cap production deploy
cap production deploy:migrate
```

2)

```
[On server - in current]
rake db:migrate
```

but none of these seem to work. How do I make this migration?

**Capistrano File**

```
lock '3.4.0'
 require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
 set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
 require "whenever/capistrano"
set :application, 'myApp'
set :repo_url, 'git...'
set :keep_releases, 5
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git..."
set :scm_passphrase, "..."
set :user, "..."
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/.../.../apps/appName"
namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you are using capistrano-rails you should set

```
set :migration_role, 'migrator'            # Defaults to 'db'
```

2) On server you are making migration in development environment, try

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

To run migrations with capistrano, on `production.rb` file which stays inside `/config/deploy` you have add "db" role
e.g.

`roles: %w{web app db}`

also capistrano migrate tasks works if there is a difference between `current_path` and `release_path` migrations. what you can do is remove migrations from inside `current_path` and then deploy and then migrate.